# How to set dynamic height for grid using ag grid react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I'm using ag grid React, and creating row grouping for grid data.I want to calculate grid height based on group rows. Is anyone know how to calculate grid height abased on rows and group rows.

I have created grid using ag grid react. Problem is scroll is coming in bottom of grid how to fix and other problem is my created grid is showing when I'm adding grid container height as vh like height:100vh. If I'm not putting height in vh then it is not creating grid . How to fix it